# Series evaluation: 2x^2 + 4x^4 + ...

Tags: power-series

Is there any closed form solution of the following series (assuming $0 \leq x \leq 1$)?
$$2x^2 + 4x^4 + 6x^6 + 8x^8 \ldots$$

Comment: Yes. Do you know any methods you can use to go from one power series to another?

Comment: I know what $\sum_{n =0}^{\infty}nx^n$ should be. But can't figure out the series when $n$ takes on only even values.

Comment: All right.  If you have $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$, what is $f(x) + f(-x)$?

Comment: We get only the even terms i.e. $2x^2+4x^4 \ldots $. Okay, so the only thing left to prove is that $f(x)$ is even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: put $y = x^2$, then
$$
2x^2 + 4x^4 + 6x^6 + 8x^8 + \ldots = 2y(1 + 2y + 3y^2 + 4y^3 + \ldots)
$$
You can get a closed formula for $s(y) = 1 + 2y + 3y^2 + 4y^3 + \ldots$ using the formula for the sum of a geometric series either by considering it as the derivative of the geometric series $y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + \ldots$ or by expanding $s(y) - ys(y)$.

Comment: Thanks very much for an elegant solution. I used your hint relating to derivatives!

Answer (score 0):

some hints:

> geometric-like series

> substitute $w=x^2$

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n x^{2n} = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n w^n = \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2nx^{2n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2\sum\limits_{m=n}^\infty x^{2n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\right)=\frac2{1-x^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}=\frac2{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$$$$=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$